# Как определить момент получения данных?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Помогите пожалуйста улучшить скрипт.

Есть json-файл. Я подгружаю его и мне нужно точно определить момент когда данные пришли. Вот [пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/idNM5SEAdtIyi3Ei8lWJ?p=preview) кода. Его слабая сторона в том, что проверка:

```
  if($scope.news) {
    console.log('OK');
  } else {
    console.log('NOTOK');
  };
```

выводит в консоль не верную информацию("NOTOK") в то время как данные успешно получены.

для решения проблемы я пробовал обернуть этот код в $timeout (в том же примере соответствующие строки закомментированы).

Но это плохая практика потому что я поставил интервал 1000ms, а при получении json-файла (например с сервера) может случиться задержка и этот интервал будет превышен.

С другой стороны, если с сервера json-файл будет получен быстрее чем за 1000ms, то пользователь будет лишнее время смотреть в экран, на котором ничего не происходит

В общем помогите пожалуйста переписать код по человечески

Привожу полный код:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', '$http', 
function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http) {
    $scope.getNews = function() {
      $http.get('news.json')
        .then(function successCallback(resp){
          console.log('success', resp);
          console.log('data', resp.data);
          console.log('status', resp.status);
          console.log('statusText', resp.statusText);
          $scope.news = resp.data.values;
        }, function errorCallback(resp) {
          console.log('error', resp);
          console.log('data', resp.data);
          console.log('status', resp.status);
          console.log('statusText', resp.statusText);
        });
    };

    $scope.getNews();

    //$timeout(function() {
      if($scope.news) {
        console.log('OK');
      } else {
        console.log('NOTOK');
      };
    //}, 1000);    
}]);
```

Comment: Вы же сами написали successCallback. Вот он - тот момент, когда запрос вернул ответ.

Comment: Это да. Но мне хотелось бы чтобы программа вообще состояла из слабосвязанных кусочков. В частности чтобы можно было по очереди вызвать все основные функции, а не одну из другой(чтобы логика не запутывалась при усложнении проекта). так в js не пишут?..

Comment: Вы либо вызываете в конце запроса следующую функцию, либо нет. Можете передавать ее аргументом, если хотеть уменьшить связность.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую перед `$http.get(...` написать `return` чтобы можно было добавлять обработчики успеха и неуспеха цепочкой из `then()` после `$scope.getNews()`. Получится вместо

```
$scope.getNews();

if($scope.news) {
    console.log('OK');
} else {
    console.log('NOTOK');
};
```

можно будет писать

```
$scope.getNews().then(function() {
    console.log('OK');
}, function() {
    console.log('NOTOK');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

первый колбэк `Promise` `.then` и есть - этот момент. Но здесь вам не нужно его определять. Суть в том, что `$news` может быть или не быть - это важно для шаблона. Вот и сделайте шаблон, в котором будет `ng-repeat` по `$news`, а если `$news` не определён или пуст - соответствующий текст. А если хотите фильтровать ответ перед отображением, то `.then(filterFn).then(otherFilterFn)` - отличное место для этих целей, но [Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) может быть лучше.

Comment: я не понял, что ты хочешь сказать в своем ответе. Как я понимаю к вопросу относится только первое предложение?

Comment: с какой целью интересуешься? К вопросу относится всё.

Comment: с той, что в данный момент не ответ не отвечает навопрос

Comment: По прежнему считаю, что отвечает. Внимание вопрошающего резонно обращено на, архитектурно обусловленную для Angular, точку связи модели и представления. Декларативный биндинг в слое представления характерен и общепринят для это фреймворка. Далее рассмотрена наиболее очевидная задача, ради которой автор собирается "определить момент получения данных" - и обращено внимание, что,  нежели попытки императивно контролировать асинхронные процессы, лучше использовать чистые функции и фильтры. Далее, опять-же, в случае Angular, каноничнее - `| filter` в шаблоне.